# knitr: exporting to html file but keeping style

Tags: css, r, knitr, kable, kableextra

I just found out the awesome `knitr` library in R, when viewing the result in the `viewer` it seems nice. However, when I write this to a html file the style is lost.

**Code**

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

some.table <- 
  data.frame (
    x = rep(1,3),
    y = rep(1,3)
  )

some.table

x <- kable(some.table, format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left")

x

file <- file('test.html')
write(x, file)
```

**Table in viewer**
[image]

**Table in browser** 
[image]

How can I export the table with the same style to a html file?
**Note** that I have more data in the html file, so I should be able to append it.

---

**Response to comment(s)**
User: @Hao
When I use `'inspect element'` in the Rstudio viewer, I can find this link to a stylesheet:
[image] 
However the code herein seems to be huge as it is `582.298` characters.

Comment: You will need to attach the corresponding CSS to the HTML files. I can add a function in the next version. Should be very easy.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I should do that (i.e. where I can find the corresponding css file) @Hao

Comment: See my question edit: response to comments @Hao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way of doing this is to put the code inside a rmarkdown document. It will handle everything for you.

The only case you need to use the save_kable function kableExtra is that you have lots of tables and you want to save them as fragments. In that case, you can use

```
library(kableExtra)
cars %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  save_kable()
```

Comment: Nice! One question though, I want to append it to an existing html file such that I can add some text above and under the table, I should adjust the code for this right? As the save_kable() will overwrite it

Comment: How is the existing file being produced?  Putting everything into an R Markdown document is the recommended way to do this, but if the HTML arises some other way, you can still put just this table into an `html_fragment` and copy that into the web page.

Comment: @user2554330 After I read the po's comments, I realized that I sort of misunderstood this question. If you need to add texts, etc to the table, I would recommend you to use rmarkdown as well because it offers you a very flexible environment to express yourself and kableExtra was actually built for that. I will edit my answers.